# Firebase database Object.toString()' on a null object reference error

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

So i have a viewholder which has the name of the user and Under it i wanna put the last message that this user received , i have a query that gives me the last node in the database there is my code :

```
Query lastQuery = allDb.child("ReceivedMessages").child(mCurrent_user_id).child(list_user_id).orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
                    lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                String message = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue().toString();
                                friendViewHolder.lastMessage.setText(message);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            //Handle possible errors.
                        }
                    });
```

and this is my database structure (also i'm sure that the referance is correct because whenever i assign all of the data to a textView it gives me the last node plus the message and date etc .. but i only want the message )[image]

and this is my error 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will do the job.

```
Query lastQuery = allDb.child("ReceivedMessages").child(mCurrent_user_id).child(list_user_id).orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnaphot.getChildren()) {
            String message = ds.child("message").getValue().toString();
            friendViewHolder.lastMessage.setText(message);     
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        //Handle possible errors.
    }
});
```